# How to deploy .yul contract with Hardhat?

Tags: hardhat, yul

I would like to deploy a contract written in pure Yul with Hardhat but I'm not sure how to do it.

Is there some plugin for it, or do I just need to add special fields to the `hardhat.config.js` file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely possible, the only pre-requisite is to **have the Yul compiler set-up already**.

---

As long as you manage to compile the `.yul` contract down to the bytecode and ABI, you can just pass them directly to the `getContractFactory` function, like this (*I used the Remix IDE Yul compiler to compile the `Token.yul` file*):

```js
// scripts/deploy_Token.js

// We require the Hardhat Runtime Environment explicitly here. This is optional
// but useful for running the script in a standalone fashion through `node <script>`.
//
// You can also run a script with `npx hardhat run <script>`. If you do that, Hardhat
// will compile your contracts, add the Hardhat Runtime Environment's members to the
// global scope, and execute the script.
const hre = require("hardhat");
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")

async function main() {
  // paste the bytecode from the compiler output:bytecode:object argument as a string literal
  const bytecode = '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'; // require('../contracts/Token.json');
  // paste ABI as a const or load the abi from a JSON file
  const abi = require("../contracts/TokenABI.json").abi;

  const ERC1155Token = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory(abi, bytecode);
  const deployed = await ERC1155Token.deploy();

  await deployed.waitForDeployment();

  console.log(
    ` Done! Contract deployed to ${deployed.target}!`
  );
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Then you should see something like this logged after `npx hardhat run scripts/deploy_Token.js`:

`Done! Contract deployed to 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3!`

*That approach with instantiating a contract factory based on the ABI and the bytecode is just a bit more complicated than just doing something like that (something that you'd normally do for Solidity files):*

```js
const MyContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract");
const contract = MyContract.attach(
  "0x..." // The deployed contract address
);
```